# Exception handling with C# & ASP.NET when trying to save data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Just trying to save user data input from a form to a database but keeps throwing exceptions. I'm semi new at coding and would appreciate any help you can provide. here is my code.

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

 public partial class subscribe_Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Registration.Registration reg = new Registration.Registration();

    reg.Name = txtName.Text;
    reg.Age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
    reg.Sex = txtSex.Text;
    reg.Address = txtAddress.Text;
    reg.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    reg.Phone = Int32.Parse(txtPhone.Text);

    this.InsertRegistration(reg);
    phSuccess.Visible = true;
}

public void InsertRegistration(Registration.Registration reg)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString)) 
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Procedure", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                var parameterName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                var parameterAge = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                var parameterSex = new SqlParameter("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                var parameterAddress = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                var parameterEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                var parameterPhone = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAge);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSex);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAddress);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmail);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterPhone);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAge);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSex);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAddress);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmail);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterPhone);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
}
```

My class as well

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Registration
{
public class Registration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
}    
}
```

My database procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure]
@Name VARCHAR(50),
@Age VARCHAR(50),
@Sex VARCHAR(50),
@Address VARCHAR(50),
@Email VARCHAR(100),
@Phone VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Users(Name, Age, Sex, [Address], Email, Phone)
VALUES(@Name, @Age, @Sex, @Address, @Email, @Phone)
END
GO
```

Every time I enter data into the fields of my form it brings up an exception of

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=App_Web_5rrjgvhs
StackTrace:
   at subscribe_Registration.InsertRegistration(Registration reg) in c:\Users\*mycomputer*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite1\subscribe\Registration.aspx.cs:line 68
   at subscribe_Registration.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\*mycomputer*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite1\subscribe\Registration.aspx.cs:line 25
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
InnerException:
```

Please note I am fairly new at programming so I'm still learning.

Am I doing anything wrong? could someone explain why this is happening? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding values to parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing values to the parameters. See in below code that after defining the parameter, `.Value` property of the parameter is set in next line.

```
public void InsertRegistration(Registration.Registration reg)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Procedure", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                var parameterName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                parameterName.Value = reg.Name;
                var parameterAge = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                parameterAge.Value = reg.Age;
                var parameterSex = new SqlParameter("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                parameterSex.Value = reg.Sex;
                var parameterAddress = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                parameterAddress.Value = reg.Address;
                var parameterEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                parameterEmail.Value = reg.Email;
                var parameterPhone = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                parameterPhone.Value = reg.Phone;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAge);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSex);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAddress);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmail);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterPhone);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Also, you are adding the parameters twice. I have removed the second set of adding parameters to the command.

Comment: Remove your try catch and paste the exception message here

Comment: I dont get any errors if I remove the try catch. But the data isnt being written to the table...

Comment: Ok, then instead of `throw ex`, you write `Response.Write(ex.Message);` and paste that here.